# Get the last value selected in vuetify v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I would like to ask on how to get the last value selected/removed in vuetify v-select with multiple prop.

Example:
v-select has items [ 'Choice A', 'Choice B', 'Choice C', 'Choice D']. If I click Choice B, I would like to get the value 'Choice B'. If I then chose another item, let's say 'Choice D'. I would like to get only the value of that item, in this case 'Choice D'.

V-select items: [ 'Choice A', 'Choice B', 'Choice C', 'Choice D' ]

Events I would like to happen: Choose 'Choice B' --> v-select model is [ 'Choice B' ] --> Choose 'Choice D' --> v-select model is [ 'Choice B', 'Choice D' ]

Answer (score 0):

Thes seems you are using multiple options in [v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#multiple).
Remove the `multiple` props from `v-select` for avoiding multiple selections.